# How can I write on a "type=text" form popup?

Tags: python, selenium

With a selenium script I create youtube playlists but I can't perform the `send_keys` function to add a name to my playlist, it always gives me an error no matter how I find the element.

I tried to click the element and then type, focus on the pop-up and then type but nothing works.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='n']").send_keys("Test_playlist")
```

After typing a name a button to create the playlist should be clickable.

Comment: What is the error? I wouldn't be surprised if Youtube is blocking your bot.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you have to trigger the onchange event after entering the value.